# Merge multiple InnoDB tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, merge

I have a big InnoDB table (7 million records) and I need to speed up the insert/update operations.
For instance, this is what the table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(year, barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I thought about partitioning the table by year:

```
CREATE TABLE product_2016 (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(year, barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE product_2017 (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(year, barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to read from the union of all the partitioned tables, so I need to merge them in some way, like you can do with the MERGE engine:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(product_2016, product_2017) INSERT_METHOD=LAST;
```

Of course I cannot do it in this way because the MERGE engine only works with MYISAM tables.

Is the VIEW an alternative? I don't want to slow down the read operation (the read time should be the same). Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Yes, you could use a view to combine the two tables, but that would be for read-only, and not inserts. Or, you could combine the tables into a single table, and then partition that based on the year field into however many partitions you require - one for each year. Using the single partitioned table would be much less of a pain within your code, as it would be automatic, and you would also have less issues when you reach 2018 :)

Comment: Thanks @DaveRix, I'm checking the partitioning in MySQL. Let's suppose I have another column like month and want to create a partition for each <year, month>. Can I do it with partitioning or do I need to use subpartitioning?

Comment: Why do you think this will improve insert/update performance? What updates do you do?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz do you think the insert/update will be the same? Just to add another info: every update statement is done using the primary key or an index of the records.

Comment: I think it might even reduce the performence. Do you update single rows or large batches?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I thought about partitioning because, in the reference manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update-speed.html) says "An update statement is optimized like a SELECT query with the additional overhead of a write". An update on a smaller table should be faster, but maybe I'm missing something. The updates and inserts are done in large batches (it depends, maybe 50 records or 4000 aswell)

Comment: Are there only two columns in the table?  Show us an example `UPDATE`.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Older versions were very inefficient when `INSERTing` into a partitioned table.

Comment: Do you use "transactions"?  Or do you update one row at a time?  How many inserts/updates are you performing per second?  What type of disk do you have (spinning vs SSD)?

Comment: You can save a little by shrinking the table:  There is a `YEAR` datatype that takes 2 bytes (versus the 4-byte `INT`).

Comment: The table have a lot of fields, some fields are mutable, some of them are for denormalization. I use an ORM that doesn't group insert/update statement, so I have a lot of "update <table> set f1 = 'value', f2 ='value', ... where id = <id1>" repeated thousand of times (same with the insert). We have spinning disks in our servers.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has a built-in partitionning system, why not using it instead of creating several tables then merging them ?

CREATE TABLE product (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(year, barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY LIST(year)(
    PARTITION product_2016 VALUES IN (2016),
    PARTITION product_2017 VALUES IN (2017),
    PARTITION product_2018 VALUES IN (2018)
 );

Mysql will split table into 3 files. It will speed up search in index because each index is smaller. It will enhance concurrent access.

But for performance reasons, it is better to partition table in lots of files something like :

CREATE TABLE product (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(year, barcode)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY KEY (barcode)
PARTITIONS 150 ;

I wonder why you have trouble to insert or update this table, 7 million rows, is not that much, I've got partitionned tables with 270 million rows and I don't have trouble with them.

Do you have concurrent inserts or updates ?

Also as year key is not very discriminant (only 2 values 2016 or 2017), it is better to put bar code first in your primary key like that :

CREATE TABLE product (
    year int not null,
    barcode varchar(8) not null,
    primary key(barcode, year)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
PARTITION BY KEY (barcode)
PARTITIONS 150 ;

Not only it will be quicker for Mysql innodb engine to recreate index when you insert a row but there won't be lock only on that file when an insert is done, so other inserts can be done at the same time on other files.

I see that you are talking about MyISAM engine, please note that MYISAM has traditionnaly locks problem, but if your table is partitionned properly, you won't have such lock problem on MYISAM table, so to consider if you have much more selects than inserts/updates and no transactions.

Comment: yes, I have concurrent inserts and updates

Comment: so your problems might come from locks from concurrent accesses and partitionning solution I explained above might reduce dramatically such locks.

Comment: 1. Smaller index does not imply faster seek. 2. Seek on partitioned index without the partition key has a  performance penalty linear to the number of partitions

Comment: I agree, but in sample, the only index was primary key and he has trouble with insert/update not with seeking. if search includes criteria on partitionned key (I suggested barcode), only one index will be used.

Comment: If there are a maximum of 20 concurrent users performing inserts or update, the number of files might be reduced from 150 to about 50 without any effects on locking issues

Comment: InnoDB does _not_ "recreate index" when you insert a row.  It updates _one_ 16KB block, and it does it in the background.  This is whether the table is partitioned or not.

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-locking.html "REPLACE and INSERT now lock only those partitions having rows to be inserted or replaced"